# How would you go about implementing this in react?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I have something like this. I assume it's an accordion.
Everything works great, but that damn black line is confusing the hell out of me. How is it that it still remains there, even when the accordion is closed.

[image]

[image]

This needs to be implemented in React, with MaterialUI.

How could I go about this?

What I have tried so far is this:

```
<div>
      <Accordion elevation={0} disableGutters={true} >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id="panel1a-header"
        >

          <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        
        <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}></div>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
            malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
```

The above code works almost great, but when I close the accordion the black line closes with it

Comment: Can you phrase your question better? What are you asking?

Comment: @Matt how could I phrase this better? 
I want to implement the UI component that you can see on the provided pictures.
The accordion with that black stripe at its bottom that stays there no matter if the accordion is expanded or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the bottom border using `sx` prop inside `Accordion`. Then you dont need to create separate `Div` for border.

```
...
<Accordion
 elevation={0}
 disableGutters={true}
  sx={{
    '.MuiAccordionSummary-root':{
      borderBottom:'1px solid black',
    },
  }}
>
...
```

Comment: Ah, instead of sx I used style at first, and it put the black line under the whole expanded accordion, not like this. Rookie mistake smh